# How to access a file using relative path or virtual path?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read and display a file using MapPath as follows :

```
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"
    Dim FilePath As String = MapPath("../Document/123.pdf")
    Response.WriteFile(FilePath)
    Response.End()
```

This procedure will work fine and display in the browser. However, if I save the file to C:\Document\123.pdf, how can I access this file using relative path in MapPath function. Is there an option to access the file which is saved out of IIS server? I am using vb.net 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a file outside the web site, you don't use `MapPath`. Just use the absolute path directly:

```
Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Document\123.pdf";
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with absolute path and it's working fine. Thank you.

Comment: May I know the best practice to display the PDF file in the browser ?